# Why does phase get kicked back during refraction?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, refraction

I've just watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KTzGBJPuJwM) video from 3Blue1Brown which explains how prisms works, but when he talks about the "phase kickback" that light undergoes when passing through a layer of a medium he says that it lags behind exactly one quarter of a cycle behind. Why is that? I've tried reading chapter 30 of the Feynman lectures (which Grant says is where viewers should look if they wanted a explanation for it), but didn't find the answer I was looking for. Can anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is in Chapter 31 (not 30).

Comment: Have you tried a [site search](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=phase+change+refraction)? There seem to be plenty of questions/answers re: phase change during refraction.

Comment: It's not on Chapter 31, quoting from the video description:

"Much of this video is based on the following Feynmann lecture
https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_31.html

The explanation for why the phase of a wave produced by a plane of oscillating charges is a quarter phase behind the wave of a charge in the center of that plane, and hence a quarter phase behind that of a light wave inducing the oscillations, is given in the previous chapter:
https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_30.html"

And yes, I've looked site-wise but no posts seemed to give a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 5):

We start by determining the field due to to a sheet of charges harmonically oscillating in phase with frequency $\omega$, and then relate its phase to the incident field that causes this motion. Suppose the sheet is situated on the $xy$-plane, with sheet current density $\vec K = K\hat x$. The magnetic field just outside the sheet can be determined using Ampere's law very close to the sheet (on a loop like that pictured [in this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/253027/171547), with $|z| \ll c/\omega$). Just outside the sheet on the side with $z > 0$, it turns out to be
$$\vec B = -\frac{\mu_0K}{2}\hat y.$$

Note the direction is consistent with the right-hand rule.

Outside the sheet, the field is a plane wave traveling outward (see the solution [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinusoidal_plane-wave_solutions_of_the_electromagnetic_wave_equation)), where $\vec E = -c\hat z \times\vec B$, so just outside the sheet we have

$$\vec E= -\frac{c\mu_0K}{2}\hat x = -\frac{c\mu_0}{2}\vec K.$$
This is what we wanted to show, the key point being the E-field is in the direction opposite to the current density (i.e. is $180^\circ$ out of phase with it).

Now, suppose that the incident wave has a frequency that is low enough that the charges in the sheet can respond to it almost instantaneously, with no delay. This isn't *always* true (see [the Lorentz model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_oscillator_model) for a more general approach), but neither is the premise of your question. If we think of a charge $q$ (e.g. an electron) bound to a fixed location in the film (e.g. a nucleus) by a spring-like force with spring constant $k$, the displacement of the charge is then
$$x = \frac{q}{k}E.$$
The sheet current density is proportional to the charge times the its velocity, i.e.
$$K \propto q\frac{dx}{dt} =\frac{q^2}{k}\frac{dE}{dt},$$
and so the E-field due to oscillating charges immediately outside the sheet is
$$E_\text{sheet} \propto -K \propto -A\frac{dE}{dt}$$
where $A$ is a positive constant.

Now we have all the necessary ingredients. If just outside the sheet we have $E = E_0\cos(\omega t)$ with $E_0 > 0$, then
$$E_\text{sheet} = A\sin(\omega t)$$
$$E_\text{net} = E_0\cos(\omega t) + A\sin(\omega t) = E_0'\cos(\omega t + \phi)$$
where $\phi$ is the phase shift with $-90^\circ < \phi < 0^\circ$, since the second term lags behind the first by $90^\circ$.

Comment: Could you elaborate why $0^\circ<phi<90^\circ$? I think for a driven harmonic oscillator the phase can vary by $180^\circ$. Does the `left out phase'  have to do with faster-than-$c$ phase velocity?

Comment: I was sweeping this issue under the rug by assuming low frequency. Otherwise, the phase of oscillations (i.e. $x$) can be $-180^\circ$ to $0^\circ$ relative to the field. With the additional $-90^\circ$ phase that comes from $E_\text{sheet}\propto-A\ dx/dt$, the phase of $E_\text{sheet}$ is $90^\circ$ to $270^\circ$. Adding this to the incident field (assumed greater in magnitude), the net field has phase shift $-90^\circ<\phi<90^\circ$. And this is why the premise of the question isn't always true: the phase shift can be positive, corresponding to a phase velocity greater than that in vacuum.

Comment: thanks for this elaboration!

Answer (score 3):

It is because of the surprising fact that the radiation part of electric field of an oscillating plane of (positive) charge on the line perpendicular to the plane is proportional to minus velocity of that charge (at retarded time), not to minus its acceleration at retarded time, as would be the case if the radiation field was due to a single oscillating point charge. Thus, since velocity is harmonic function of time, the phase of the radiative field generated by the slab is shifted by quarter of a period compared to what one would expect from a single radiating charge.

Feynman explains why that is the case in section [30-7 **The field of a plane of oscillating charges**](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_30.html#Ch30-S7), analyzing the integral estimating superposition of fields of all contributing charges in the slab (for a much simpler way to get the same result, based on the Ampere law applied to the current sheet and the educated guess that its EM field is a plane wave, see Puk's answer). Feynman shows that radiation field contributions of individual charged particles take different times to reach the observing point $P$ and this means those field contributions are proportional to phase factors at various different times, depending on how far the contributing charge element is from $P$. The fact these phase factors are position-dependent has the surprising effect that the resulting net field of the charge plane is proportional to velocity of the charge, thus to current density in the plane, not to acceleration of the charge.

Since position, velocity and acceleration of the oscillating charge are all harmonic functions of time, velocity of the positive charge in the slab is oscillating (as function $\cos \omega t$) with quarter period lead compared to its position (oscillating as the function $\sin \omega t$). But position is in phase with the external electric field (by assumption, the medium is linear and lossless, so polarization is proportional and in phase with total electric field, and thus in the case of thin weakly interacting slab, also with the external incoming field). Thus newly generated field is oscillating as the function $-\cos \omega t$, which is one quarter period behind $\sin \omega t$, describing the external field.